# CentOS environment: How to delete docker repository from docker hub, using linux command line

Tags: centos, docker

I would like to delete a docker repository from dockerhub, using the command line.

I am using CentOS.

Like the below is used in GUI Docker hub website to delete it (the following picture shows step)
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a third party website's functionality.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for your comment, I've changed my question content, hopefully, the quesiton quality is more good than before,thanks again

Comment: The management of a docker repository is specific to docker hub.  There are third party tools (eg https://github.com/amalfra/docker-hub ) which may help with CLI access, but this is not really a "Unix/Linux" related question.

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks and please help me how can I do. how can I release this issue to which forum?

Comment: You may be able to do it with curl, but something like that will probably end in pain. You will probably loose all of your work. And how often do you do this operation, is it worth automating. See Parito 80 20 rule. 20% of operations will be done 80% of the time.

Comment: If the action were possible and supported it would be documented on docs.docker.com.   The action is neither possible nor supported except via the website,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below picture step
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the API allows working with the repos on CLI, to delete a repo you must log in and use the website.
https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-delete-a-repository